# Getting Spring Boot to load annotated resources defined inside runtime dependencies

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-annotations

I am developing a bunch of Java/Sprint Boot webservices that will all have several identical (ideally, reusable) Spring-based resources:

- many annotation-based Spring Security configurations
- several `@Service`s and `@Component`s
- many annotation-based event handlers
- annotation-based exception handler

  - `@ControllerAdvice` that `extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler`
- annotation-based configuration files (`@Configuration`)

Ideally I could place these in a library (shared JAR file) and reuse them across the different webservice projects. However I don't believe Spring Boot will scan the entire dependency graph of libraries and load them based on their annotations.

Does anybody know of a way to *encourage* Spring Boot to do this? For example if I package the following class into a reusable/shareable library JAR:

```
@ControllerAdvice
@Slf4j
public class ApiExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler implements ApiContractConstants {
    // ... common exception handling code to be used by
    // all services
}
```

And then pull that in to a Spring Boot webservice (via Maven/Gradle) as a runtime dependency, how do I get Spring Boot to scan, find and load that exception handler for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The description makes me think of @SpringBootApplication. The property scanBasePackages of @SpringBootApplication defines base packages to scan for annotated components.

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"org.example"})
```